# Civimember: token for membership end date not working

Tags: civimail, civimember, tokens

We are having a problem in setting up our Scheduled Reminders for Membership Renewals. The reminders are sent out as scheduled, but the relationship between Contact to Membership (which is through a foreign key in the database) seems to be broken as far as inserting tokens into the renewal email.

For example, adding lines to our Expiration Template like:

Paid thru: {membership.end_date}
Member since: {membership.join_date}

only replaces the tokens with blank in our email tests.

I found [this reference from 2015](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36009.0) in the old CiviCRM Community Forum, but am re-posting here. I can't believe this is an unresolved issue. I use other membership software, like aMember PRO, and this is one of the most basic functions in renewal reminder emails.

If it has been resolved, please point me to a solution. My searches in this Stack Exchange haven't worked for me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What version of Civi are you using?  Which CMS?

Comment: Sorry I didn't add that. CiviCRM 4.7.12 with WordPress 4.6.1

Comment: Also, just discovered this link after googling around. https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken If I need this, why isn't this basic core functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll call this an answer, only because it worked. I discovered this link after googling around. civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken
After installing the extension, my Expiration Template now contains:

> Your membership is paid thru: {latestcurrentmembership.allend_date}
>
> Member since: {latestcurrentmembership.alljoin_date}

Since this seems a practical necessity for Membership-related Scheduled Reminders, I updated the documentation for Membership > Renewals to point to this extension for others who wish to associate membership information to the contact in the reminder.

Comment: hi Karl - as a free open source project most of what gets added to civi is done because someone is able to contribute the work, or the funds. So it is always helpful when firing in a 'please' to indicate if you can contribute either. Beyond that, there may be other reasons why contributions of work remain as extensions rather than being incorporated in to core code but I can't offer a technical reason in this case. Lastly, another way to contribute is through improving documentation, so if there is somewhere that you think some signposts could be added then please give it a go.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and I will take a whack at the documentation - there are two places for it, under Scheduled Reminders and under the specific pointer to Membership Renewals. Such signposts would have helped me as that was where I first looked. This is our first CiviCRM instance, somewhat on trial. If it sticks we'll certainly contribute funds and possibly work, too, if we really get into it.

Comment: Excuse me for asking a simple question, from a subversion (not git) person. I created a git clone on my win 10 desktop where I have GIT GUI and GIT Bash installed. I edited just one file docs/membership/renewals.md. I committed to my local working copy and want to push it back to the master branch. Note my SSH keys are all set up with github.com. What URL should I use to push it back? Will it only send the one file, or will it try to create a new branch? I'm hoping there is some sort of review process before accepting and don't want to mess anything up. Thanks for any little help here.

Comment: Actually, instead of working from a clone, I read the README.md and then simply forked and edited that single page in my browser. I then put in a comment and created a pull request. Is that all there is to it?

Comment: sounds right. put the PR here and someone might engage

Comment: Pete - it was reviewed and committed. Since I'm a real believer in good documentation, it's nice to know there is a good process in place. Thanks again for pointing me to that.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the documentation change, accepted it, but I could not +1 it because it was my own answer. Oh well ;)

Comment: then i will +1 it ;-)