# Fuzion token {latestcurrentmembership.end_date} blank in scheduled reminder based on membership - works in mailings. Alternative?

Tags: civimember, tokens, scheduled-reminders

We use the Fuzion Tokens extension and it's great! We have a membership expiration alert message template using {latestcurrentmembership.end_date} and it works perfectly well in mailings. However, in testing scheduled reminders, I see that for a record where the value displays appropriately in the mailing, it's blank in the email sent by the reminder.

The reminder is based on the membership expiration date and it works. All the tokens display in the drop-downs for Email Screen in the schedule reminder interface. What else might be going on? What can I check? Is there a native token I could use instead? This is CiviCRM 5.50.2 on Wordpress 6. Thanks for any ideas!

Update: same problem with this particular token in scheduled mailings. The fix is to use {latestcurrentmembership.allend_date} instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better answer! I found this older question: [Civimember: token for membership end date not working](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16196/civimember-token-for-membership-end-date-not-working?rq=1) for scheduled mailings, and it also works for reminders! The working token is {latestcurrentmembership.**all**end_date} - that "all" makes it work. Sorry if there's Fuzion documentation about this that I missed!

Answer (score 2):

I used a workaround which gives the same result. Because the reminder triggers based on the expiration date, I plugged in a Smarty snippet that will match the expiration and created new templates to use just for the reminders. So for the "one week before" I have `{$smarty.now+24*60*60*7|date_format}`, and for "two days before" `{$smarty.now+24*60*60*2|date_format}`. Not as elegant but accomplishes the goal.